# How Do I Carry Out Unicode Searching in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, unicode

I was under the impression that searching for non English Unicode characters strings can be carried out in the same way as English character strings. But it appears that searching non English Unicode words fails in Google Calendar (upper part of the image below).

[image]

I am carrying out the test searches for this task. When I search with the English string `BUET`, the search is successful *(lower part of the above image)*. But when I search with a non English Unicode word, the search is not successful.

[image]

I have tested with other non English Unicode words, the searches were not successful. I use the same keyboard (input method) to create tasks in the calendar and to input words for search. *(Though this should not be an issue as long as the text encoding remains unchanged.)*

Is there anything wrong in the way I am searching? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I can successfully search for unicode characters that are relevant to me (`æøåÆØÅ`)

Comment: No, it still fails for my case (Bengali). I just checked again. And what is funny, I tried Greek using Google translator to add and search event, it worked. Really puzzling.